# Can't load plist animation in cocos2d "No animations were found"

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x, sprite

I'm new to cocos2dx and I've got a C++ project on Windows using cocos2dx 3.9 and I'm referencing the **File Animation** example from this page [http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Sprite_Sheet_Animation](http://pastebin.com/kZpcCEgp); I'm unable to get the plist to load the animation.

When I try to load the plist:

```
auto cache = AnimationCache::getInstance();
cache->addAnimationsWithFile( "explosion.plist" );
```

The log shows:

```
cocos2d: AnimationCache: No animations were found in provided dictionary.
```

What am I missing?

Also, I'm not sure what to use in place of `"dance_1"` in the example. Is it simply the first animation frame key?

http://pastebin.com/kZpcCEgp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above spritesheet which you are using doesn't have the extension
>   .png in all the files. You can create a new spritesheet from texture
>   packer.
>
> To get a sample spritesheet, first goto
>   `**~your-cocos-directory/cocos2d-x-3.9/tests/cpp-tests/Resources/zwoptex/**
>   and copy grossini.plist & grossini.png to your Resources folder.
>   [Sample plist Link](http://pastebin.com/XxWGk1WY)

Now to run frame animation from a spritesheet, then first add the frames using the following command:

```
SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("grossini.plist");
```

Now add the frames in animation cache:

```
Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames(15);
char str[100] = {0};
for(int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
    sprintf(str, "grossini_dance_%02d.png",i);
    auto frame = SpriteFrame::create(str,Rect(0,0,40,40)); //we assume that the sprites' dimentions are 40*40 rectangles.
    animFrames.pushBack(frame);
}
```

Now run the animation

```
auto animation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, 0.2f);
auto animate = Animate::create(animation);
sprite->runAction(animate);
```

Hope it helps.